# Makefile:124: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am creating Makefile and it gives me following error

```
    Makefile:124: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'. Stop.
```

The Makefile around line 124 is

```
    .PHONY: popiso
popiso: isolinux_cfg $(foreach x,$(_$(country)_pops_roles), pop_iso_$(x)) $(isomedia)
@echo $@
@echo
@echo allhostname $(allhostname)
@echo
@echo
@echo allnetwork_setup $(allnetwork_setup)
@sudo cp $(addsuffix .ks.cfg,$(allhostname)) $(isomedia)
@sudo cp isolinux.cfg $(isomedia)/isolinux/
@echo ready to make iso
```

$(_$(country)_pops_roles) gets expanded correctly and it calls pop_iso_XXXX 4 times as it suppose to.
And then it gives above mentioned error.

I'm using RHEL6 - 64bit machine
I'm not that deep into Makefile/Gmake, and so I'm not sure what's the issue.

```
$ make -v

GNU Make 3.81

Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Hemanshu

Edit: Remake version: run using 'remake all -X'

This is how the main line expands

```
popiso: isolinux_cfg pop_iso_loc2_role1 pop_iso_loc2_role2 pop_iso_loc1_role1 pop_iso_loc1_role2 /raw/ops-xxxx/media
```

It makes first 5 targets successfully and then stops as follow

```
end pop_iso_loc1_role2
/raw/patel/xxxx-build-test/build-tools/ks/Makefile:166   Successfully remade target file `pop_iso_loc1_role2'.
<- (/raw/patel/xxxx-build-test/build-tools/ks/Makefile:166)
pop_iso_loc1_role2
remake<19>
-> (/raw/patel/xxxx-build-test/build-tools/ks/Makefile:119)
/raw/ops-xxxx/media:

remake<20>
/raw/patel/xxxx-build-test/build-tools/ks/Makefile:124     Must remake target `popiso'.
Makefile:125: *** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'.  Stop.

***Entering debugger because we encountered a fatal error.
** Exiting the debugger will exit make with exit code 2.
popiso
remake<21>
```

then for testing purpose I removed sixth target '/raw/ops-xxxx/media' but error still says the same

Comment: Are you sure this is the line causing that error message?

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) -with its `-x` flag- to debug such bugs.

Comment: Error message says for line 124, which is the line after foreach command. line foreach is 123rd one. I'll check with remake.

Comment: So `isomedia` aka `/raw/ops-xxxx/media` depends on `popiso` (circular dependency?) and ends up calling the recipe again with some of the variables unset and/or botched? Not sure this is the explanation but that's what I make of the available information.

Comment: `$(isomedia):
        $(noop $$(pmkdir $$@))
        @echo end $$@
`  There doesnt seems a circular dependency though.it just create destination directory.

Comment: @tripleee : I also tried by removing $(isomedia) all togather to check if that's the culprit. But nope, it haluts at the same location with same error message weather of not $(isomedia) target is there.

Comment: How much *else* can you remove, and still get the same error?

Comment: @Beta: Upsii, I did remove everything and still the error stays there. It is like                                                all: popiso mkiso

.PHONY: popiso
popiso:isolinux_cfg $(foreach x,$(_$(country)_pops_roles),pop_iso_$(x)) $(isomedia)
I removed everything and just popiso: @ echo SOmething, and still the error is same. I'm puzzled now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, and I doubt that you're showing us the real makefile. Please give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Of course I'm not giving complete make file and mentioning only portion where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "it calls pop_iso_XXXX 4 times as it suppose to".

That proves that the problem is not in this foreach(). If it were, I would expect that the foreach would not get expanded at all.

The following brief, standalone Makefile, works correctly and gives the expected results without errors:

```
_a_pops_roles=foo bar

country=a

popiso: $(foreach x, $(_$(country)_pops_roles), pop_iso_$(x))

pop_iso_foo:
    echo 1

pop_iso_bar:
    echo 2
```

This usage is identical to what you have.

Look for other foreach loops in your Makefile, where the problem actually is.

For example: you have another call on the same line to $(isomedia). If this macro expands out to a foreach, and it has a syntax error, this would be reported as an error on this line even though the typo is somewhere else.

You can't always trust line numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $(isomedia) just creates the destination directory if it doesn't exists. I have tested the script with full debug, it doesn't report any error, that's an issue. without any error I don't have anything but line number to go with.

Comment: The pop_iso_foo/bar is also phony and they are defined as                                                            define popiso_pop_role
.PHONY: pop_iso_$(1)_$(2)
pop_iso_$(1)_$(2): isolinux.cfg.head rpms.m4 ks_network.cfg.m4 
        @echo Hemanshu